# Remove an item from array of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression

I have list of variables/items

```
dbTemp = [Type,Threshold,TypeID,Prioirty,Value,Assign]
```

where `Type,Threshold,TypeID,Prioirty` are variables
Let's say, their values are `1,0,2,0,NULL,21`

If a variable value is `0` or `NULL`, I need to remove/exclude them from the list and build a dynamic variable expression based on the non-zero or non-NULL values

In this case, `Dynamic Expression = Type>0+TypeID>0+Assign>0` (excludes `Threshold`, `Priority`, `Value` variables since their values are `0` or `NULL`)

Can you please help me here?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What's a "dynamic variable expression"?

Comment: if value of any of the variable is 0 or NULL, I need to exclude them from the expression...

Comment: variable values are not same for all the scenarios, it will differ for each scenario say, dbTemp = [Type,Threshold,TypeID,Prioirty,Value,Assign]

Comment: dbTemp = [0,0,0,0,1,NULL] or [1,1,1,2,0,1]

Comment: Why do you need to exclude them? `null` will be treated as `0` when you do `value > 0`. This will return `false`, which becomes `0` when you do the sum, so they won't contribute to the total.

Comment: I need to exclude them to build an expression... final exp will be like Expr = Type>7&&Threshold>7&&.... Based on the expression my routing application will pick the best possible agent (who are greater than 7) and route the call..

Answer (score 1):

filtered here:

```
var filtered = dbTemp.filter( function(el) { return !!el; } );
```

will contain all non null or zero elements from dbTemp;

Comment: Why do you need `!!`? `filter` does its own truthiness test, it doesn't need you to convert the values to booleans.

Comment: How do I do it without the function call?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on some condition(s) instead of just filtering falsy values:

```
var filtered = orignalArray.filter(function(item) {
    return (item !== condition1) && (item !== condition2);
});
```

p.s. NULL !== null

Answer (score 0):

If you'll allow for any falsey value and a result that is a filtered copy, then this will suffice:

```
var result = dbTemp.filter(Boolean);
```

---

If you actually need to mutate the original and order doesn't matter, then do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dbTemp.length; i++) {
    if (!dbTemp[i]) {
        dbTemp[i] = dbTemp[dbTemp.length-1];
        dbTemp.length--;
        i--;
    }
}
```

---

If the original order does matter, then this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dbTemp.length; i++) {
    if (!dbTemp[i]) {
        dbTemp[i].splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```